# Boostrap 5 Horizontally center navbar

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

On the Bootstrap 5 documentation, it says use "justify-content-center" class to horizontally align a nav element.

```
<ul class="nav justify-content-center">
  <li class="nav-item">
    <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link</a>
  </li>
  <li class="nav-item">
    <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link</a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Reference: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/components/navs-tabs/#horizontal-alignment

How do I horizontally align a navbar? Adding "justify-content-center" to navbar-nav does not work. Is there an elegant way to achieve this using BootStrap's internal classes and not writing custom CSS?

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Navbar</a>
    <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#navbarNav" aria-controls="navbarNav" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
      <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
    </button>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNav">
      <ul class="navbar-nav justify-content-center">
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link active" aria-current="page" href="#">Home</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="#">Features</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="#">Pricing</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link disabled">Disabled</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

Add `justify-content-center` class in collapse div like below

`<div class="collapse navbar-collapse justify-content-center" id="navbarNav">`

Update: justify-content-center will align contents as center in `<ul>` but you have `<ul>` in `collapse navbar-collapse` so you need to center your `<ul>` within this div.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).